# How do I reduce the use of onmouseover and onmouseoutt?

Tags: javascript, html

On my page I numerous sections that I want to highlight when the mouse goes over.  This can be accomplished using `onmouseover` and `onmouseout`.  I have more than 100 sections though and I don't think that it is very efficient to call the methods on each section.  Like so.

```
<li id="1" onmouseover="h(1)" onmouseout="h(1)">
    <label>1</label>
</li>
<li id="2" onmouseover="h(2)" onmouseout="h(2)">
    <label>2</label>
</li>
<li id="3" onmouseover="h(3)" onmouseout="h(3)">
    do something
</li>
...
<li id="4" onmouseover="h(4)" onmouseout="h(4)">
    do something
</li>
```

I'm hoping to get this answer in Javascript as I do not know jQuery.

Comment: Depending on what specific effect you're after, this may be possible with simple CSS; no JS required.

Comment: if on css it is great , i am using google chrome and i want to try my page on chrome and firefox

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are after is **event delegation**. That is binding the event handler to a common ancestor. In your case it could be something along the lines:

```
// assuming `ul` refers to the list element that contains those `li` elements
ul.onmouseover = function(event) {
    // some cross-browser handling (IE)
    event = event || window.event;
    var target = event.target || event.srcElement;

    // if the event was triggered on a `li` element
    if(target.nodeName === 'LI') {
        h(this.id);  // do the stuff
    }
};
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/JVp8S/)

This is only an example and you have to adjust it to your needs, e.g. if the `li` elements contain elements themselves, things are a bit different.

I recommend to read [the great articles on quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html) if you want to learn more about event handling.

---

That said, [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) would make this a lot easier, also because it simulates the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events from IE, which are much more useful, and takes care of the cross-browser issues.

For example:

```
$('#listId').on('mouseenter', 'li', function() {
    h(this.id);
});

$('#listId').on('mouseleave', 'li', function() {
    h(this.id);
});
```

If you work a lot with event handling and/or DOM manipulation, jQuery is really to be recommended.

Answer (score 1):

```
<li id="1" class="btn">
do something
</li>
```

js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function(){
       var allBtns = document.getElementsByClassName("btn");
       for (var i = 0; i < allBtns.length; i++) {
         allBtns[i].onmouseover = function(){h(this.id)};
         allBtns[i].onmouseout = function(){h(this.id)};
        }
     }
</script>
```

---

or:

```
<ul class="myBTNS">
   <li id="1">do something</li>
   <li id="2">do something</li>
<ul>
```

js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
        var btnsContainer = document.getElementsByClassName("myBTNS");
        for (var i = 0; i < btnsContainer.length; i++) {
            var allBtns = btnsContainer[i].getElementsByTagName("li");
            for (var i = 0; i < allBtns.length; i++) {
                allBtns[i].onmouseover = function() {h(this.id)};
                allBtns[i].onmouseout = function() {h(this.id)};
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

​

Comment: this function i have to wirte it directly on my js or inside a function ?

Comment: is there any other way to get that array ? i mean without using className , cos each section on my page have different class

Comment: @WilliamKinaan you can just add class to `<lu class="myBTNS">` then get all `li` children of that class

Comment: @WilliamKinaan An element can have multiple classes, use a new class to link that element with the mouseout/over functionality. I've updated my answer to demonstrate this.

Comment: i did that , but it doesnt work , is it cos i have to put ur code into a function or what ?

Comment: @WilliamKinaan See here: http://jsfiddle.net/eVs9L/ press ctrl+shift+j to open Googles javascript console to see the output.

Comment: my li containst elements like lable and input , is this cos it doesn't work ?

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` is [not supported](http://caniuse.com/getelementsbyclassname) in IE 8 and below.

Comment: Yes.  A good part of the world still uses IE 8 and so it seems inappropriate to give the OP an answer that doesn't work for the majority of Internet users.

Comment: @dunsmoreb instead of looking into others answers and vote them down try to give anwsers and be more ...

Answer (score 1):

Pretty simple solution:

**HTML:**
For each `<li>` elements which you would want to perform an action once the mouse is placed over / out, assign a class value. In this example I have used the class name '`someclass`' however you could change this to whatever you feel best suits it. Please also note that an element can have multiple classes. e.g. `<li class="someclass anotherclass"></li>` .

```
<ul>
  <li class="someclass secondaryclass">Example</li>
  <li class="someclass">Example</li>
  <li class="someclass">Example</li>
  <li class="someclass">Example</li>
<ul>​
```

**JavaScript:**
Loop through all elements with the class name 'someclass', and attach the event listeners. In this example I have mitigated the '`out`' and '`over`' function declarations, however look at the jsFiddle example bellow to see them in action.

```
for(var i in document.getElementsByClassName('someclass'))
{
    document.getElementsByClassName('someclass')[i].addEventListener('mouseover', over ,false);
    document.getElementsByClassName('someclass')[i].addEventListener('mouseout', out ,false);   
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eVs9L/ <-- view the Browser console to see the output of the mouse over / out function output.

**jQuery approach:**

```
$('.someclass').hover(function(){
  //Mouse Over Code goes here...
}, function(){
  //Mouse Out code goes here...
});
```

Comment: but every "li" has different class on my page , is there any other way to got that array using something like 
    getElementBy...(li) ?

Comment: @WilliamKinaan  
You can use the following: class="classA classB classC"

Answer (score 0):

Yes, answer is using jQuery .each.

Link: http://api.jquery.com/each/

Answer (score 0):

You can use document.getElementsByTagName to get all you li elements and store them in an array.  Then it is just a matter of looping through the array and assigning a function to the onmouseover and onmouseout events.

```
var elems = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    elems[i].onmouseover = function () {
        this.innerHTML = "over";
        this.style.background = "yellow";
    };
    elems[i].onmouseout = function () {
        this.innerHTML = "out";
        this.style.background =  "white";
    };
}
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/jumpnett/2kCSS/3/) is a link to a demo in jsFiddle.  I made the function change the text and bg color just to demonstrate the the code is actually doing something.

Comment: is it possible that my browser doesn't allowing writing FOR dircetly on my JS file , i mean without function ?

Comment: my li contains elemetns such as label and input, is this cos it is not work ?

Comment: Try this version http://jsfiddle.net/jumpnett/rSSQu/ It shows the page as implemented in a single html file.  You don't need the event handlers in the markup, since they are being handled in the JS.  Also, it needs to be in an window.onload function to be run on startup.